# Animate maps in R

Tags: r, animation, jquery-animate, jpeg

[image]Hi every one. I just finished a seriesof rasters overlaid with vector maps. how do i save them as individual jpeg or png files? how do i animated them? i stacked and trid the "animate" command but it did not show the vectors. the final command line so far is below:

```
 ANIM<-lapply (FINA,function(x) spplot(x, scales = list(draw = TRUE),xlab= "Longitude (°)",
 ylab="Latitude (°)", xlim = c(-18,17), ylim=c(2, 27.5)) +
 latticeExtra::layer(sp.polygons(WAN, fill = NA, col = 'black')) +
 latticeExtra::layer(sp.polygons(NND, fill = NA, col = 'blue')))
 grid.text(expression ("molecules  " ~ cm^-2), x=unit(.95, "npc"),y=unit(0.50, "npc"), rot=90)
```

this plots the maps out nicely in a run until the last plot but how do i save all the 36 of them as an animation or a series of jpeg files wuth unique titles on them, please? 
The command that works for exporting a single jpeg file is:

```
 dev.copy(jpeg,'A.jpeg',height=600, width=900)
 dev.off()
```

Comment: Have you looked at the r `animation` package?  Also the ffmpeg program is good for this sort of task.

Comment: This question may answer your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19918126/create-animation-with-ggplot-wiht-map-data-in-r?rq=1

Comment: Seth, it answers half the question but doesn't answer the export. I would like to play d animation in another environment outside r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it easier to execute this in RStudio by printing the ANIM list.

```
print(ANIM)
dev.off()
```

THis plotted each scene. I then saved each one of the plots in the ANIM list as a png file serially. Using the back arrow, i went back to the first plot and kept saving till i got to the last one. the saved plots were available to use in other packages. I then inserted them in windows movie maker. Thanks everyone.